# Android - Как вывести на экран сколько используется cache-памяти в приложении

Tags: android

Я работаю с приложением, в котором используется большое количество изображений.
Как можно вывести на экран сколько используется cache-памяти в приложении в мегабитах ?

Comment: [Нет никакой необходимости](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610/177345) добавлять в заголовок то, что указано в метках. В данном случае "Android" в заголовке совершенно лишнее слово.

Answer (score 3):

Использовать MemoryInfo

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
long usedMemgs = (mi.totalMem - mi.availMem) / 1048576L;
long percentAvail = mi.availMem / mi.totalMem;
```

Comment: здраствуйте андрей , вы правы спомощью MemoryInfo можна получить памятные данные устройства , а как получить размер cache памяти которую использует приложение ???